# OnChangeText in react native textinput not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my textinput onChangeText method, I am adding values to an array but it keeps adding a new object for every single chararcter.
Expected :

```
[
  {
    "desc1Name": "876",
    "desc2Code": ""
  }
]
```

Current Scenario :

```
[
  {
    "desc1Name": "8",
    "desc2Code": ""
  },
  {
    "desc1Name": "87",
    "desc2Code": ""
  },
  {
    "desc1Name": "876",
    "desc2Code": ""
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: can you give me some detail about your function or your component ? why you need to add value onChangeText ?

Comment: i think you need an button or a trigger when you finish change or release keyup